# Can I process an OLAP cube through GUI

Tags: c#-4.0, olap, olap-cube

I have a program which uses a multidimensional database and I need to add a feature to the GUI for the users to process the cubes through it.

Is there a library to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What brand of multidimensional database is this? Microsoft SSAS? Cognos? Pentaho?

Comment: It's a Microsoft SSAS. I was able to make it by creating a SQL Job and calling the msdb.sp_start_job procedure from within my application.